# Android - cannot update listview with filtered results from edittext string

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, contactscontract

I'm experiencing some problems filtering contacts on the phone by the search string typed by the user in an edittext.

It seems like it's filtering well, but the problem is that the filtered ListView contains the same initial contacts as the ALL CONTACTS ListView.

For example:

```
ALL CONTACTS:
A - B - C - D - E
```

I write E in the `EditText` and, using a `TextWatcher`, the filtered result is `A`.

So it's like it's filtering well (only one result), but the listview content has not been updated!

Some code here:

`getFilter()` and custom filter:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() 
    {
    if (mFilter == null) 
    {
        mFilter = new CustomFilter();
    }

    return mFilter;
}


private class CustomFilter extends Filter 
{
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) 
    {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        Log.d("PREFIX", "its ---> " + prefix);

        prefix = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

        if(prefix != null && prefix.length()>0)
        {
            ArrayList<Contact> contatti = new ArrayList<Contact>();

            for(int i = 0; i < _app._contacts.size(); i++)
            {
                Contact current = _app._contacts.get(i);

                if(current.getContactName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(prefix) /*|| current.getNumber().toLowerCase().contains(prefix)
                        || current.getEmail().toLowerCase().contains(prefix) || current.getOrganization().toLowerCase().contains(prefix)*/)
                {
                    contatti.add(current);
                    Log.d("added to contatti list: ", current.getContactName()+" - "+current.getNumber());
                }
            }

            results.count = contatti.size();
            results.values = contatti;
        }
        else
        {
            results.count = _app._contacts.size();
            results.values = _app._contacts;
        }

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) 
    {
        ArrayList<Contact> risultatoFiltro = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        risultatoFiltro = (ArrayList<Contact>) results.values;

        MyAdapter filteredAdapter = new MyAdapter(_ctx,R.layout.listview,risultatoFiltro);

        MainActivity.lv.setAdapter(filteredAdapter);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Edited publishResults method:

```
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) 
    {
        if (results.count == 0)
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        else
        {
            ArrayList<Contact> risultatoFiltro = (ArrayList<Contact>) results.values;

            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();

            //Add the items back in
            for (Iterator<Contact> iterator = risultatoFiltro.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) 
            {
                Contact contactList = (Contact) iterator.next();
                add(contactList);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the filtering works well, but if I delete some characters the list doesn't update!

Example: write 'Daniel'. If I delete all except 'D' the list remains 'Daniel'! And if I delete the 'D' the list is not the initial one, but it gives me an empty list!

Can you help me figuring this?

Comment: have you tried my given solution for your problem?

Comment: @PratikSharma I took a piece of code from another answer and it seems pretty similar to your in the way it works. See my edited question, can you help me with my last problem please?

Comment: I tried your version of the publishresults method and it works well, but when I delete part of the string I have the same problem as reported in the edited question!

Comment: can you please put log inside your publishResults method for `results.count` and `constraint` by entering some name to filter and delete characters from the string?

Comment: sorry, my collegue resolved that, it was a problem with the same list used by different threads. he just cloned this list and used that in the filtering thred, et voilà! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @TheCondor can you post the answer please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not working on this project anymore and I also don't have access to the source now..

Answer (score 1):

Try out in the following manner :

```
@Override
public void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        List<T> filtered = (ArrayList<T>) results.values;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter.clear();
        if (filtered != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < filtered.size(); i++)
                adapter.add(filtered.get(i));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

}
```

Comment: tried it, works well except for the deletion of the string, the problem is described in the edited question. thanks!